# How to calculate centrifugal force with gravity or accelerometer sensor in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-gps

I need to calculate centrifugal force with available sensors (gravity, accelerometer or GPS) when car is turning. But I'm not sure how to make it. Maybe you can give me and advise?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Use Pythagoras on this sensor that already excludes gravity. I haven't tested this but you get the idea.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);

accelSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {
            x2 = Math.pow(event.values[0], 2);
            y2 = Math.pow(event.values[1], 2);
            z2 = Math.pow(event.values[2], 2);
            centrifugalForce = Math.sqrt(x2 + y2 + z2);
       }
 }

mSensorManager.registerListener(accelSensorListener, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```